# How to create custom attribute for products without using eav attribute table?

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

I have different price for products based on cities say for example

> 1. Pune = 100
> 2. Mumbai = 120
> 3. Bangalore = 140.

I planned to create a custom table in that fields will be id, mumbai_price, pune_price, bangalore_price.

Now my question is whether to create custom attribute in product field or any other way is there to do. Because cities can increase.

Can anyone suggest me what exactly to do?